# Anchor Build Depenedency error

Tags: anchor, cargo

I am trying to compile an anchor package and whenever I type anchor build or cargo build-bpf get this error -

```
**error: not a directory: '/Users/madhavgoyal/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.10.31/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf/dependencies/bpf-tools/rust/lib'**
```

I have reinstalled cargo and rust quite a few times still not able to figure out how to solve this

Comment: Can you let us know how you installed Solana?

Comment: Used this command **sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.10.32/install)"** and when i type solana --version 
get - solana-cli 1.10.31 (src:77a40cd8; feat:4192065167)

Comment: It seems strange that you tried to install version 1.10.32 and got 1.10.31... you may want to try deleting all of the solana directories and retrying

Comment: oh I had installed it earlier but copy pasted the new command sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try deleting your cache

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/solana/v1.10.32
```

or

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/solana/*
```